# Problems by using two Access Runtime 2003 and 2010 in windows 7 64bits

Tags: ms-access, windows-7, ms-access-2010, windows-7-x64, ms-access-2003

Environment:

- Windows 7 64bits
- Runtime Access 2003 32bits
- Runtime Access 2010 32bits

We need to install 2 access runtimes in Windows 7 64bits, versions 2003 and 2010 because we are using databases of these two databases.

I updated a pc from a Windows XP that worked out well, and now with this windows 7 there is any way to make this work.
It works when I install each of them separately but when they are both installed together, there is no way.

The last runtime I install, it is the database that it works for the first time, when I open the other runtime makes something when changes the runtime and then fails.

**Errors I get.**
After changing from Access Runtime 2010 to 2003 (using Access 2003):
 - I get this error "OpenForm" is cancelled

[image: When I try to print something in program that uses A2003 mdb, executing with A2003]

I tried to use only Access 2010 and I got this error:
- it can not be determined the version installed of executable Access14.

[image: When I try to print something in program that uses A2003 mdb, executing with A2010]

And then I tried to open directly the 2003 database with Access 2010 and I got this other error:
- Read only database or database without convert from a previous version of PRTSICINMED

[image: PRTSICINMED with A2010]

How can I make this work?

Comment: You should develop in the lowest version of MS Access that you need, so install Access 2003 32 bits and compile in that version.

Comment: A huge database is already created on Access2010 and an old accountability program uses Access2003, so no way to go back :s

Answer (score 0):

You can make this work. As a general rule since you want a particular application to launch + use Access 2003, and then another to launch + use 2010, then you need to build a shortcut for each application.

The shortcut for 2003 will look like this;

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office11\MSACCESS.EXE" 
"c:\RidesDev\SkiRides\RidesXP\RidesXP.mde" /runtime
```

And for 2010, it will look like this.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\MSACCESS.EXE" 
"c:\RidesDev\SkiRides\RidesXP\RidesXP.accDE" /runtime
```

Note that above examples are on two lines here for ease of reading + posting, but the above shortcuts are on one line separated by a space in the actual shortcut you create.

Note that shortcuts are the SAME for full edition of Access or runtime (you cannot install both full + runtime of the same edition of Access on a machine – only one is allowed and thus above path names never change between full or runtime edition).

However, keep in mind that the above will likely cause a “re-configuring” and “installing” message to appear each time you SWITCH versions since the LAST version of Access run has to be correctly registered and setup on the computer. (and yes, this “hi-jacks” the access file extensions which is why the above shortcuts are required). So last version of Access will "set" the file extensions if you click on a database without using above shortcuts.

Keep in mind that in MOST cases the access 2010 runtime will “happy” consume the 2003 mde, and the 2010 accDE.

As a result, I would VERY MUCH consider dumping the use of the 2003 runtime, and have the 2010 runtime execute both the 2003 and the 2010 application.