# Office365 VBA's Recordsetclone prompts for a data source

Tags: vba, ms-access, office365

I maintain an Access DB that I built a few years ago when Office 2010 (32bit) was the standard. We've recently upgraded to Office 365 (also 32bit).  This db is *very* dependent on using `Me.Recordsetclone` to do stuff.  For example:

```
Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)
    Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
    Set rst = Me.RecordsetClone
    'Do stuff
End Sub
```

Now that Office has been upgraded, when the code calls `Me.RecordSetClone`, the 'Select Data Source' Dialog box shows up. When I try out the same code on an RDP we having running 2010, it works normally. Based on that and what little I can find on the net, I think it's a library switching/version issue.

The only work-around I can think of is to have the users run both versions side-by-side and switch back and forth.  But that would be a maintenance headache.  Can anyone suggest a better alternative?

[image]

Comment: Same as Gustav - `Form.RecordsetClone` is a DAO method. When I run your two lines in Access 2010, I get a `Type mismatch` on the second line. Is your database an ADP?

Comment: @Andre, no. This is a simple ACCDB which I publish as an ACCDE to a network drive.  The bug pops up in both ACCDB and ACCDE versions.

Comment: As I said, I can't understand how this ever worked. Have you tried changing it to `Dim rst As DAO.Recordset` ? It's a simple enough change.

Comment: I did try that and got the same error.  Have you seen my responses to Gustav? Does that help?

Comment: Yes (I have) and no (sorry, it doesn't).

Comment: In any case, it does work just fine with the Office 2010 libraries. If I dual install both versions of Office on the users machine, can I force it to always look at the older version?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/28761312/3820271

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen ADO used for this, only DAO:

```
Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Set rst = Me.RecordsetClone
    'Do stuff
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @Gustav, I think I hardcoded this as ADODB because it worked and I was having problems with DAO (I made this years ago so I can't give you any specifics). It's equally likely I just went with the first thing that worked.  In any case, I tried this in a test db and nothing changed. The Select Data Source is still popping up.

Comment: This form is populated by first pulling the data into a DAO recordset which is then used to populate a ADO recordset when is then attached to the form with `Set Me.Recordset = rstAdo` . This was the recommended method at the time to do what I wanted (allow users to check boxes without immediately saving it to the backend). If there's a workaround to this versioning issue that doesn't require me to rewrite this whole thing from scratch, I'm listening.

Comment: I can't tell. I've never worked with the disconnected recordsets. Couldn't see any advantage.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue and seem to have rectified by changing my recordset clone reference from

`Me.*Subform*.Form.RecordsetClone`

to the following

`Set Rst = Forms!*Mainform*.Form!*Subform*.Form.Recordset.Clone`

I hope this helps.